# Want to make a list equal to a target length by inserting every element next to its presence starting from 0th index until condition is satisfied

Tags: python, list

I want to make a list equal to a target length by inserting every element next to its presence starting from 0th index until length condition is satisfied.

I have written below code
If I give length of the list more than 45, it works and reaches my target length of 90 for that list.

```
import pandas as np
target=90
lst =list(range(45))
diff= abs(target-len(lst))
for i in range(0,diff*2,2):
  lst.insert(i,lst[i])
print(lst)
```

output:[0,
0,
1,
1,
2,
2,
3,
3,
4,
4,
5,
5,
6,
6,
7,
7,
8,
8,
9,
9,
10,
10,
11,
11,
12,
12,
13,
13,
14,
14,
15,
15,
16,
16,
17,
17,
18,
18,
19,
19,
20,
20,
21,
21,
22,
22,
23,
23,
24,
24,
25,
25,
26,
26,
27,
27,
28,
28,
29,
29,
30,
30,
31,
31,
32,
32,
33,
33,
34,
34,
35,
35,
36,
36,
37,
37,
38,
38,
39,
39,
40,
40,
41,
41,
42,
42,
43,
43,
44,
44]

```
len(lst)
```

But it is not working for length of the list below 45.

```
target=90
lst =list(range(44))
diff= abs(target-len(lst))
for i in range(0,diff*2,2):
  lst.insert(i,lst[i])
print(lst)
```

```
len(lst)
```

Error : IndexError: list index out of range

Output should be like the above 1st case and final length of the list should be always 90 at all condition when the given list is smaller than the specified target length.

could some one help me please how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the second one, you have `diff = 90 - 44 = 46`. The value of `i` in your loop can reach 92. The length of `lst` is 44. `diff * 2 = 92`. `i` can reach 92 meanwhile `lst,` wouldn't have the index to correspond: `46`, because it stopped at `44`.

This problem probably wouldn't exist if `lst` range was >=45. You may be looking to use `list.append()`? Or if `lst` has to always have 90 elements, you can initialize it with 90 and then use your `list.insert()` calls.

Comment: how to sort this out now, I need my list to be 90 doesn't matter how small it is.

Comment: `lst = [None]*90` or maybe `lst = [0]*90` or maybe `lst = [-1]*90` or...

Comment: Its nowhere helpful

Comment: What exactly is the issue?